# Transparent background becomes white while showing in imageview

Tags: android, imageview, blob

I am getting blob of a image from server and storing it into database. The image has a transparent background. But when I retrieve the data from database and show in an imageview the transparent background becomes white.

Comment: Your Image View Background is White Or grid view background is White.So the transparent reflect the background of Views color.

Comment: Do you store the image as JPEG at some stage of your process? If so, the transparency is lost forever.

Comment: thanks everyone. The problem is solved. actually the problem was not at android end it was the fault of the server as they dont save the image as png